# How to use flow interface without it complaining about "interface" being a future reserved word in strict mode?

Tags: flowtype

I am using flow to create an interface that I want some classes to implement :

```
// @flow

export default interface Client {
  connect(): any;
  getFile(): any;
  uploadFile(): any;
  deleteFile(): any;
  end(): any;
};
```

But when I run `flow check` I get the following error :

```
3: export default interface Client {
                  ^^^^^^^^^ Use of future reserved word in strict mode
```

I am following the [Interfaces types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/) and [Modules types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/) pages of the Flow documentation, on which I didn't find a solution to my problem.

My version of flow is 0.49.1.

Does anybody have a solution to use interfaces ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you just can't make it the default export. This passes:

```
/* @flow */

export interface Client {
  connect(): any;
  getFile(): any;
  uploadFile(): any;
  deleteFile(): any;
  end(): any;
};
```

I'm not sure if Flow supports making any type a default export. I've never done it and have never felt the need to try.